# Login in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an idea of how to use `post` method for login, however, our new requirement is my API team has provided `get` method. How is this used in angular? Please help me. I am stuck on this problem as I am new to angular. Below is the API for `get` method:

> `http://183.82.48/HospitalManagementSystem/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/{EMAILID}/{PASSWORD}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to construct the URI yourself.

```
<form ng-app="login" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
  <span>Email</span><input ng-model="emailId" type="text" required><br>
  <span>Password</span><input ng-model="password" type="password" required><br>
  <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</form>
<script>
var app = angular.module('login', []);
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.login = function() {
    $http.get('http://183.82.0.48/HospitalManagementSystem/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/' + $scope.emailId + '/' + $scope.password).then(
      function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        // ...
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // ...
      }
    )
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i got the solution

Comment: hi @trand how to display the logged in user name in my home page

Comment: @Sudhir If there is any information in the response returned by your login API, you can add to the markup: `<span>Welcome back, {{username}}!</span>` and the response callback: `$scope.username = response.data.user.name;`